# svychisq test in R run on 2x2 tables

Tags: r, survey

I am reading about the svychisq test in R (part of survey package). Is this test specified only for 2x2 dimensional tables (i.e., two dichotomous variables, 0/1).

I have been able to run the test on larger tables 2x5, without an error. thanks! Any clarifications would be appreciated!

Comment: **All** the examples on the help page are larger than 2x2

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem doing that.  Here's an example with the `apuclus1` data from the `survey` package:

```r
library(survey)
library(dplyr)
data(api)
apiclus1 <- apiclus1 %>% 
  mutate(growth_group = cut(growth, 5))
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
svytable(~growth_group+awards, dclus1)
#>             awards
#> growth_group        No       Yes
#>   (-34.2,-1]  473.8579    0.0000
#>   (-1,32]    1116.9509 1489.2678
#>   (32,65]     169.2350 1861.5848
#>   (65,98]       0.0000  880.0219
#>   (98,131]     33.8470  169.2350
svychisq(~growth_group+awards, dclus1)
#> 
#>  Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment
#> 
#> data:  svychisq(~growth_group + awards, dclus1)
#> F = 13.987, ndf = 2.4081, ddf = 33.7139, p-value = 1.457e-05
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>